# Flex Spark datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

i have an error adding dataprovider on my spark datagrid:

```
Multiple initializers for property 'dataProvider'. (note: 'dataProvider' is the default property of 'spark.components.DataGrid').
```

My data is from `s:httpService` declaration and i put it in data grid something like this

```
<s:DataGrid includeIn="formState" x="348" y="57" width="287" dataProvider="{myHttpService}">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="data1" headerText="Data Field 1"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="data2" headerText="Data Field 2"></s:GridColumn>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="data3" headerText="Data Field 3"></s:GridColumn>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
    <s:typicalItem>
        <fx:Object dataField1="Sample Data" dataField2="Sample Data" dataField3="Sample Data"></fx:Object>
    </s:typicalItem>
    <s:ArrayList>
        <fx:Object data1="data1" data2="data1" data3="data1"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object data1="data2" data2="data2" data3="data2"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object data1="data3" data2="data3" data3="data3"></fx:Object>
        <fx:Object data1="data4" data2="data4" data3="data4"></fx:Object>
    </s:ArrayList>
</s:DataGrid>
```

and my http service is:

```
<s:HTTPService id="myHttpService" url="http://host.com/mydata.php"/>
```

Comment: Try your dataprovider as {myHttpService as ArrayList}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code specifies the dataProvider twice, inadvertently I think.

The first time it is specified as a property on the tag, on this line.

```
<s:DataGrid includeIn="formState" x="348" y="57" width="287" dataProvider="{myHttpService}">
```

The second time it is specified as a child of the DataGrid, with these blocks:

```
<s:ArrayList>
    <fx:Object data1="data1" data2="data1" data3="data1"></fx:Object>
    <fx:Object data1="data2" data2="data2" data3="data2"></fx:Object>
    <fx:Object data1="data3" data2="data3" data3="data3"></fx:Object>
    <fx:Object data1="data4" data2="data4" data3="data4"></fx:Object>
</s:ArrayList>
```

You can't specify the dataProvider in both cases.

Additionally, I'll add that your code, as is, is using myHttpService as the dataProvider (in thef irst line).  You probably want to use the results of the myHttpService call as the dataProvider; not the actual myHttpService object.

I believe you could bind to [myHttpService.lastResults](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#lastResult) if you wanted, by my preference is to have a formal results handler that deals with handling the results,  Conceptually like this:

```
<s:HTTPService id="myHttpService" url="http://host.com/mydata.php" result="onMyResult(event)"/>

protected function onMyResult(event:ResultEvent):void{
  this.myDataGrid.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(event.results as Array);
}
```

Comment: i see, I understand now. Thanks for making it clear! Great answer